# Parsing a codechef leaderboard and display it in a different site with different metric validation

Tags: javascript, jekyll

Im making a contest with codechef and i need to use various types of metrics to validate each challenge .

I only have the source code size as a metric in the site and i also need execution time and memory spend .

This last two are given if a response is accepted .

So i need a way to parse the leaderboard and display it on the site 3 different leaderboards with each leaderboard in javascript .

Any help is accepted specially on the way to update the leaderboard

Comment: you need to edit the question, to include what you've done so far, and where you've got blocked. cf [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). so you'll help improving the content of this site, and the possibility to get good answers

Comment: yaitloutou i really dont know how to do any off this , im literally lost